# PHP is printing an empty column from MySQL even though it is not empty

Tags: php, mysql

I am printing a 3 column MySQL table on a webpage. Everything prints out except for the second column, its just blank.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    if (!$connection)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

mysql_select_db("MEASURE", $connection);

$numberz = 54;

mysql_query("INSERT INTO measurement (DATA)
VALUES
('$numberz')");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM measurement"); 

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>DATA</th>
<th>TIME</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";             
echo "<td>" . $row['DATE'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['TIME'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($connection);
```

This is what I get on my webpage:

```
ID  DATA    TIME

1   2013-02-26 14:32:26

2   2013-02-26 14:32:26

3   2013-02-26 14:32:27
```

Notice how the second column is blank

Here's how the table looks in MySQL:

```
ID | data | TIME                


|  1 |    1 | 2013-02-26 14:32:26 |

|  2 |    1 | 2013-02-26 14:32:26 |

|  3 |    1 | 2013-02-26 14:32:27 |
```

Comment: Please do not write in all caps.

Comment: where did you printed 2nd column?

Comment: `echo "<td>" . $row['DATE'] . "</td>";` You put DATE...shouldn't it be DATA?

Comment: You have a typo in your code, `$row['DATE']` should be `$row['data']`

Comment: Is your field `DATE` or `DATA`?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a simple typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

if you table field name are ID, data, TIME. you are using capital and wrong field name.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM measurement"); 

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>DATA</th>
<th>TIME</th>
</tr>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td>";             
echo "<td>" . $row['data'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['TIME'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 3):

Where you are printing out to the page you are accessing `$row['DATE']` which looks like it should be `$row['DATA']`

Comment: It was exactly that plus it should of been not capital letter it seems like. I spent hours on this can't believe it was a typo. Much appreciated thanks!!!